# Use generic interface in struct generics

Tags: go, generics

I have the following generics interface:

```
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"

type IProto[P proto.Message] interface {
  ToPB() P
  SetPB(proto.Message) error
}
```

which I would like to use for a generic struct:

```
type Foo[T IProto] struct{
  Field T  
}
```

The idea is to be able to define functions of Foo that will use ToPB and SetPB and return values of type P, e.g.:

```
func (f *Foo[T]) DoSomething() P {
  return f.Field.ToPB()
}
```

I get `cannot use generic type IProto[P protoreflect.ProtoMessage] without instantiation` error.

What is the correct syntax for that?

Comment: Can you do this without generics, like https://go.dev/play/p/usQgQ-ALfo0 ?